# simplexml_load_string gives inconsistent xml tags

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am getting inconsistent XML tags when parsing XML string with Simple XML in PHP

```
$str = '<?xml version="1.0"?><toplevel><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google maps"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google translate"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google docs"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google drive"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google classroom"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google news"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google earth"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google flights"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google calendar"/></CompleteSuggestion></toplevel>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$data = json_decode(json_encode($xml),true);
echo "ARRAY: <pre>";
var_dump($data);
```

In the above case, I'm using the auto completion from google and it respond with suggestions within CompleteSuggestions tag. Looking at the php array, I get a CompleteSuggestion array with 10 items. The first 9 have a key of [0] while the last one have key ['suggestion']. This is very strange to me.

Does any one know why Simple XML does this? And how I can fix it, or parse it since my foreach is getting an offset error. Thanks!

Comment: What version of php are you using? On 5.6 the result is ["CompleteSuggestion" => [/* array of 10 elements*/]]

Comment: PHP 5.5. I'm also getting array of 10 elements but the issues that is that each element is an array with different keys

Comment: Why, why, why, are you converting the SimpleXML object to an array, and throwing away all the useful bits of the SimpleXML API? `foreach ( $xml->CompleteSuggestion as $comp_suggestion ) { $suggestion = $comp_suggestion->suggestion; echo $suggestion['data']; }`

Answer (score 0):

That's a wierd one - I'm getting the same behaviour on 5.6 (getting numeric arrays for all of them apart from 1).

As a workaround, I've used array_pop:

```
<?php

$str = '<?xml version="1.0"?><toplevel><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google maps"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google translate"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google docs"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google drive"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google classroom"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google news"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google earth"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google flights"/></CompleteSuggestion><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="google calendar"/></CompleteSuggestion></toplevel>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$data = json_decode(json_encode($xml),true);


foreach ($data['CompleteSuggestion'] as $suggestion){
        $sug = array_pop($suggestion);

        echo $sug['@attributes']['data'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Here is that same code simplified by using SimpleXML as intended, rather than hacking with an array: https://3v4l.org/PTgjh

Answer (score 0):

Thats very interesting behaviour. I suppose, it happens because you have multiple `suggestion` tags within your xml and SimpleXML try to parse this xml as an object with a field named `suggestion` and then when parser meet another tag with the same name it converts that object into array.

So I wouldn't rely on built-in SimpleXML data structure and recomend you preprocess received data as Liam suggested.

Comment: All very interesting suppositions, but not really how SimpleXML works at all. SimpleXML doesn't actually parse the whole document into objects and arrays in advance at all, it just gives you access to the underlying document with an OO interface, like the DOM does.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Maybe you know why does SimpleXML object convert to xml in such interesting manner? I'm just curios.

Comment: Well, given that [it behaves differently in different versions](https://3v4l.org/DGYJP) I'd say it's just a bug. Note that it has absolutely nothing to do with how SimpleXML reads the XML itself, but with how it converts to JSON, which is always going to be messy because JSON and XML are just fundamentally different ways of structuring data.